# Copy database with n rows from a table within the database

Tags: sql-server

I need to get a dev database for my local setup at work. I have run into one major problem, one of the tables (which accounts for 99% of the activity on the database) is about 7GB. It's not necessary that I get all of the rows from this table, the top 10,000 or so would work.

Is there anyway in a script or anything where I can copy a database and specify how many rows from a certain table? I know its a longshot. I just don't need to spend half of my day restoring a database because of the size of one table.

Comment: Have you tried SQL Server Management Studio's Import Data?

Comment: I've never tried it, but why not use the copy database wizard to set up the SSIS package, and then edit that package with a select top 10000 somewhere in there?  The only other thing I can think of is writing your own custom SQL solution.

Comment: Restoring a 7GB backup into another SQL Server will take about 5 minutes or so. Why do you think it will take half a day? By far, restoring from a backup is the easiest thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be fancy (and who doesn't?), you could have that table on its own filegroup in production and then restore all but that filegroup in dev. Then you could create the table fresh upon restore, import some data (I'd write a simple SSIS package myself for that) and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually try few things to export (and then import) data, you can use any of following methods,

1. SSIS package
2. [SQL Server Import Export Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx) in SSMS (which can also create SSIS package)
3. Use Query Result tab, and save results as CSV
4. Use [BCP with QueryOut flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) to export data
5. Use [SQLCMD with -o](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) flag